# User name, password in UITableView? (iOS, iPhone )

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Can we use UITableView with 2 rows, one for username and the other one for password. I've noticed..some of the apps seem to be use UITableView in their authentication screen on iPhone. For example, Skype..is it a UITableView with 2 rows? (sorry I couldn't attach a screenshot..)

how can I get this working?

Answer (score 4):

i suggest you to use the CustomTable view like this[image]

and use this customTable inside the UITable Delegate method like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
MyIdentifier = @"NewsTableViewCell";
NewsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];   
cell.Username.text=@"Suresh@gmail.com";
 OR
cell.password.text=@"*******"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's UITableView with two rows. What's the problem are you facing?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how it can done..I didn't know how to make a cell editable..this is what I'm thinking should do the trick,

Comment: 1. add table view 2. then table view cell??..or can we do that in xcode..( just fyi, I'm new to this..)

Comment: Could you please point me where I can find relevant info on this?..I guess..I would like to know how I can go about it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UITableView for that. But why?

Comment: Thats a good question..just that it looks good to me...and something different than using 2 different test fields..

Comment: The work that you use a table view is probably more than 2 different fields :-P

Answer (score 0):

I think in Skype it just looks like a table view but it really is an image with labels and textfields on top.

I did something similar in my Twitter code. See the screenshot at http://github.com/st3fan/iphone-twitter

Comment: awesome..this would help me great deal..thanks!!! will take a look at the code..cheers..